# How is my (now deleted) answer "spam"?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

How is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54709338/2173917) **spam** (or **rude**, or **abusive**)?

Screenshot for below-10K users:

Deleted screen:

> [image: Deleted screen]

Expanded View:

> [image: Expanded View]

Comment: Did you maybe copy that answer to multiple questions?

Comment: @Cerbrus That is handwritten answer, apart the wikipedia link, and quite from question, every single word is typed into browser window.

Comment: Afaik if there are open rude/abusive/spam flags on an answer while it gets deleted, it's automatically displayed as rude/abusive/spam and those flags get automatically marked as helpful, even if they're very much incorrect.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't have answered the question at all. But judging just from that one answer, I see nothing that looks like spam or rude. I would call it borderline abusive if you answer a question that you're going to delete vote or close vote.

Comment: @ErikA: There are not "deletion votes" on it, though. It was spam-deleted, instead of it being a "side-effect" of it having a flag.

Comment: @Cerbrus Nope, it was deleted as part of the question getting deleted.

Comment: Oh, good point. Then that's probably what happened.

Comment: @BDL That's debatable whether the answer is warranted or not. In my opinion, that question needed a little more context than the marked dupes, as it has an additional question added to the primary problem. which I tried addressing separately. The delete vote I casted after seeing community rejection (-7) and already two delvotes on teh question. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: The post also racked-up 3 quick downvotes.  This is surely "a 100k user should know better" flagging at work.  Well, you do answer such horrible questions at your peril, crap happens when you do.

Comment: @HansPassant is there a guideline for "a 100k user should know better" flagging thingy? I thought judgements were for posts, not people. Also, a poor question does not mean a poor answer, always. I'm not trying to argue that I did the correct thing or alike, the question is about the spam flag.

Comment: @SouravGhosh no. Flagging answers as spam because "OP should know better than to answer a bad question" isn't a valid reason, nor is it one SE actually uses.. It still happens some times, because some flagger probably wants to teach someone a lesson or something. Motivation is an entirely separate topic though.

Comment: A rude or abusive flag was definitely wrong. But you have to expect downvotes if you are going to answer the 10th duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: @BDL I never asked anything about the votes - they are there for general quality or usability purpose. A spam (or rude or abusive) flag, on the other hand, is something entirely different, and more serious.

Comment: @HansPassant It's actually -7 (the +5 takes it to -2), I can understand that downvoting part and not disturbed, voting is a choice. Regarding the answering - Yes, I should have tried enhancing the question (which I would have down the line - that's the general trend I follow) but none of this clarifies the spam flag.

Comment: @HansPassant And yes, if there is a phenomena..I'd like to see a guideline. Once again, I accepted the voting (poor action from my part), but I did nothing to warrant a spam or rude or abusive flag. That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: @Zoe Right, that's what is the correct approach. Unfortunately, comments like the one I'm referring to in previous comment, encourages the wrongdoing.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: If I were to spam flag BoltClock's answer, and this question got deleted before that spam flag is invalidated, then BoltClock's answer would've been marked as "spam", like yours was. Some user just deemed it necessary to flag your answer. We can't answer "Why", we can only tell you that that's what happened.

Comment: @Cerbrus Correct, I'm not asking for that user's action. This auto-accept part of flag was not known to me. that answers the question.

Comment: That's a great example of a stupid question. It would have taken him less time to compile and run that to see what actually happens than it took him to compose the question.

Comment: @Will In the case of C, no. If it compiles, that doesn't mean it's free of UB's, so "what actually happens" depends on the compiler, the OS etc. The OP was right to worry.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Your answer was flagged as rude or abusive by someone.

Someone who, ironically, left a rude or abusive comment on your answer. (This phenomenon of harmless content being deemed rude by people who are actually rude is a common Internet trope.)

The only thing that stands out about your answer is that it compares one snippet to another using the word "bad", and the use of the same word was used to criticize your answer. But that's not nearly worth a rude or abusive flag.

I've deleted that comment and invalidated that flag.

Comment: I believe I know that "someone" and also the source of that "rudeness". Believe me or not, it's because of a cricket match result. I understand this. :)

Comment: Why exactly does self-deletion validate spam flags? That seems like something that can get abused.

Comment: @Zoe: Good question...

Comment: Funny, I didn't know that it was even possible to have a not deleted answer on a deleted question :)

Comment: A non-deleted answer on a deleted question? [HAX!](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/joke-battles/images/7/79/Haaax_5.png/revision/latest?cb=20151230233435) This will surely disrupt the space-time continuum...

Comment: I deleted the answer myself.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Maybe there should be badges for that (e.g. Anomaly, Disaster, and Chaos).

Comment: This represents a bug, however. According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175420/dont-automatically-dismiss-spam-offensive-flags-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-the/273402#273402) spam and abuse flags are not supposed to be validated when the author deletes a post. The fact that it did means that it's a bug.

Comment: @gparyani: The flag on an answer was validated when the answer-author deleted the question. Not exactly the same case, but might be worth to report as a new bug.

Comment: @Zoe How would that enable abuse? A user would have to know that a rude/abusive/spam flag was raised on their post, *and* want to have that marked against them, *and* self-delete in order to 'abuse' the system that way... in which case is that kind of self-flagellation really abuse? That seems like a Rube Goldberg method for abusing the system, at least...

Comment: @TylerH The asker spam flag an answer, then delete the question?

Comment: @user202729 Oh, the *asker*? I was assuming when Zoe mentioned "self-deletion" she meant the answerer self-deleted the *answer*. An asker can't self-delete a question when there are multiple answers, so what you describe can't be the situation Zoe describes, surely. The question was not self-deleted. The answers *were*.

Comment: @TylerH that was while I [misunderstood how it works](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7557808#7557808) - the original thought was that because some users delete heavily downvoted answers, a spam flag could be thrown in along with a couple downvotes, and if it's deleted before the flag is validated, that would result in the 100 rep penalty. At least that's already covered, which just leaves the bug as gparyani mentioned.Alternatively there's the approach user202729 mentioned:The asker flags and deletes the question, but the main concern for me was the 100 rep penalty part

Comment: which probably would give motivation for someone to abuse it. I mean, votes are already abused (serial up/downvoting, targeted voting, voting circles, even answer pairs who ask questions and someone else answers it, and it's all planned before it's posted), so it appeared to be likely the 100 rep penalty could be used as "motivation" to do it. But since that requires community deletion, that's not as much of a problem, and only leaves the bug part of it

Answer (score 26):

I'm the one who closed the question, and was slightly shocked that a high reputation user answered a blatant/unclear duplicate.

After the closure the question was heavily downvoted and the answer too.

When I came back to see the state of the question, I saw that the answer was locked as "rude or abusive", so instead of opening a meta post about that, I flagged the post for moderation attention to revert that (as the consequences on the user -you- which has a flagged post are bad, and this is not fair). Of course my flag was helpful and the spam flag was reverted.

Someone(s) must have thought that you were "abusing" the system by answering obvious duplicates. Which is *stricto senso* not the case.

Comment: Please don't make a generality of this, or of high rep users. Even this user doesn't spend his time answering duplicates. If it happens, flag as duplicate or visit a chatroom to ask for help.